# Jump at the end of a CSS transform scale transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, scale, css-transforms

Here is my code to apply a scale effect (like a zoom) on a figure element while hovering a parent.

CSS (SCSS)

```
.card-link {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure.card-figure {
  will-change: transform;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translateZ(0) rotate(0.001deg);
  transition: transform var(--transition-easing) var(--transition-duration);
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  perspective: 1000px; // Helps the jump in chrome
  backface-visibility: hidden; // Helps the jump in chrome

  // Hover
  .card-link:hover & {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1) translateZ(0) rotate(0.001deg);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="card-link">
  <figure class="card-figure">
    <img src="...">
  </figure>
</a>
```

It obviously works, but at the end of the transition it makes a little jump, like the figure goes some pixels outside the parent (that it has overflow hidden).

This seems to only happens on Chrome (v 89.0.4389.114) and only at certain viewports (window sizes).

I tried all (I mean all) the solutions I found (you'll recognize them in the CSS above) but none of them worked. Please, anyone could give some ideas? Thanks